# Using exec in node js to pass variables and a string

Tags: mysql, node.js

How do I pass variable and string to `exec = require(child_process).exec;`:

```
exec("echo mysql-server-5.7 mysql-server/root_password password %s | debconf-set-selections",myid);
```

It's not working..

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec,
    util = require('util'),
    emitter = new events.EventEmitter();

function puts(error, stdout, stderr) {
    if (error) {
        emitter.emit('error', error);
    } else {
        emitter.emit('info', stdout.trim());
        if (stderr) {
            emitter.emit('error', stderr.trim());
        }
    }
}

exec(util.format("echo mysql-server-5.7 mysql-server/root_password password %s | debconf-set-selections", myid), puts);
```